# Position Data Series Label to StipLine in SSRS Bar Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, label

I have a Bar Chart in an SSRS report that has 2 strplines that represent milestones and column that represents the actual result. There are 2 data values for each stripline that I want to add data series labels to the chart, but can't figure out how to position the labels to the striplines. Any help would be greatly appreciated.